# Are there any circumstances in which ld ignores LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: shared-library, ld

I've just come across a little problem with `ld` which I just can't explain. Let's say I have compiled a library in my home directory and installed it all under `~/root`. The shared library file can be found at `~/root/usr/local/lib/libmylib.so`.

Because `~/root/usr/local/lib` is not in the linker's search path, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as I always do:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/root/usr/local/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And check that the library is available with:

```
$ ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH/libmylib.so
/home/me/root/usr/local/lib/libmylib.so
```

Now, if I run:

```
$ ld -lmylib --verbose
```

The final lines should include something like:

```
attempt to open /home/me/root/usr/local/lib/libmylib.so succeeded
-lmylib (/home/me/root/usr/local/lib/libmylib.so)
```

Except in my case, they don't. `ld` simply does not perform any lookup under `/home/me/root`. The contents of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` simply never appear in the output, which suggests that `ld` is shamelessly ignoring the variable (and actually, my directory never appears in `SEARCH_DIR` earlier in the output).

However, if I run:

```
$ ld -L $LD_LIBRARY_PATH -lmylib --verbose
```

I do get the above lines and everything goes smoothly, which means there's nothing wrong with the library or the installation path.

Is there any circumstance in which `ld` ignores `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ? I've checked `env` and I couldn't find any other linker-related variable (`RPATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_RUN_PATH`, which were all tested). Configuration under `/etc/ld.so.*` does not appear to do anything except register some (other) directories. The machine runs Scientific Linux 7.4, gcc 6.4 and ld 2.25.1. The library in question is `libxml++-3.0`.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know `ld` ignores `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, at least for libraries specified on its command line; `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn’t listed in [the environment variables which affect it](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.30/ld/Environment.html#Environment). It *does* refer to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when [looking for libraries which are needed by other libraries](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=ld/emultempl/elf32.em;h=9b8971eac486898322c7dd4cfd64777a12b28f01;hb=HEAD#l1360), in native builds, emulating the behaviour of [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

Comment: Shouldn't `LIBRARY_PATH` have done something then? I have the same setup on another machine, and `ld` does explore the contents of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` there. `man ld` also appears to concur with that: *5.  For a native linker, search the contents of the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".*

Comment: `LIBRARY_PATH` isn’t referenced either. The only variables read from the environment are `LD_RUN_PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `COLLECT_NO_DEMANGLE`, `GNUTARGET`, and `LDEMULATION`. However `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` *is* used to find libraries which are referenced indirectly; that’s what your quote from the manpage is referring to.