# How to provide library path to ./configure script

Tags: compiling, libraries, configure

I was trying to install a library called [Openslide](https://openslide.org/) which failed during the `./configure` step because it could not find a dependency ([libjpeg](https://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/)).

I thought I would proceed to build libjpeg and then manually provide the library location to `./configure` to make it work. After building libjpeg at `~/libjpeg`, I thought I could just add `~/libjpeg/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by putting the following in my bashrc and re-sourcing it `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/libjpeg/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

This didn't work and libjpeg still couldn't be found by the `./configure` script in Openslide. I started hunting down answers online, one suggestion was to try `./configure --with-libjpeg=~/libjpeg/lib` which also failed.

I eventually gave up and just did a sudo apt install, but I am still curious as to why I couldn't manually provide the location of the library. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSlide [uses `pkg-config` to find its dependencies](https://github.com/openslide/openslide/blob/0680fb34b74fd0441af6e49f45bee8e21fc87047/configure.ac#L56), so you need to tell `pkg-config` where to find your library:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/libjpeg/pkg-config ./configure …
```

replacing `~/libjpeg/pkg-config` with the path to the directory containing `libjpeg.pc`.

Unfortunately the libjpeg implementation you used is very old and doesn’t provide a `.pc` file; you might want to use [libjpeg-turbo](https://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/) instead (that’s what `libjpeg-dev` pulls in on current Debian and derivatives).

Comment: hmm. does it matter that the `libjpeg` build on the system does not have a `pkg-config` directory? All that was in the build was `bin`, `man`, and `lib`. Also how did you know where to track that down? Was I crazy to think it could be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for this is a common mistake, not helped by the ambiguous variable name; [it’s only used by the dynamic loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449063/86440), not by the linker (directly). It doesn’t matter that your `libjpeg` build doesn’t have a `pkg-config` directory; all that matters is that it produces a `libjpeg.pc` file and that you point `pkg-config` at it.